# Another phrase like "Having a grand old time"?

Tags: phrases

Trying to find other phrases like "Having a grand old time" for an ending to our wedding invitation. Thanks so much for your help!

-Jordan

Comment: @Joe Blow: You probably meant "pigs in clover". "Pig in a poke" is something you bought that turns out to be a dud.

Comment: Terp - thanks!! That's so weird, I meant to just type happy as larry". I've been sitting around happy as an unwashed programmer today, so I probably had in mind a pig in his sty, or some such  :)

Answer (score 1):

Some terms you could use for this are:

- Celebration
- Having a blast
- Festivities
- Merriment

Answer (score 0):

It'll be [beer and skittles](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beer%20and%20skittles) for everyone.

> a situation of agreeable ease

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that grand was replaced by great in standard American English at some point. Heard it used in the radio drama "Gold-digger" 1947 recently. It must have been very common during World War II. Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: Your answer looks more like a comment and question than an answer. Please visit [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here. Please post your question by clicking "ask a question" if you have one. I would advise you to delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible phrases:

- Having a whale of a time
- Partying like it's 1999
- Whooping it up
- Eating, drinking, and being merry